# Installing a custom Root authority certificate for a Service Application

Tags: ssl, https, mmc, tls

I have an Windows service application, that executes under a specific user account, that calls a remote web service via HTTPS.  The certificate the remote server uses is issued by a Root authority that is not included as one of the default authorities installed with Windows.

As a result of this the application fails, when making the web service call, as a trust relationship cannot be established with the remote server.  In order to resolve this I need to install the Root certificate into the OS certificate store.

Fairly simple so far, however...

Where does this certificate need to be installed?  It is currently installed (via MMC->Certificates) to the Trusted Root Certification Authorities section for Local Machine.